# What is the max possible size of an 32x32px .ico file?

Tags: size, favicon, bit, .ico

I'm making a `favicon.ico` script, and I need to know the max amount of bits possible.

Comment: assuming only 1 icon in the .ico ?

Comment: The maximum size it will have will be 32x32 pixels. - jk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It maxes out at 32 bits per pixel, 24 RGB plus alpha transparency, so that would be 32 x 32 x 32, or 32768 bits.

So 4096 bytes (4K).

Comment: Of course, there are also headers, and there could be more than one size/color depth in an icon...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the number of colours you are using.

For 8bit (256 colours):

```
32 * 32 * 8 = 8192 bits
8192 / 8 = 1024 bytes
1024 bytes = 1Kb
```

For 32bit (16.7 million colours):

```
32 * 32 * 32 = 32768 bits
32768 / 8 = 4096 bytes
4096 bytes = 4Kb
```

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29).

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a single ico file can contain up to 65,535 images (see [header description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29#Icon_resource_structure)). That would mean that the maximum number of pixels could be as large as 65535*32*32, which at 4 bytes per pixel comes to 268,435,456 bytes.

Comment: Such a file would be pretty silly, though -- there'd be no basis for the consuming program (app or OS) to prefer any particular image, if they all have the same color depth and size! (Also, headers take space too.)